# highlightFilter angularjs error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a angularjs app but it gives me an error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/$injector/unpr?p0=highlightFilterProvider%20%3C-%20highlightFilter
at http://localhost:63342/AdminLTE-2.3.11/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
at http://localhost:63342/AdminLTE-2.3.11/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:41:240
at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:63342/AdminLTE-2.3.11/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:220)
at http://localhost:63342/AdminLTE-2.3.11/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:41:314
at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:63342/AdminLTE-2.3.11/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:220)
at http://localhost:63342/AdminLTE-2.3.11/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:150:456
at X (http://localhost:63342/AdminLTE-2.3.11/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:112:209)
at http://localhost:63342/AdminLTE-2.3.11/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:110:334
at p (http://localhost:63342/AdminLTE-2.3.11/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:355)
at X (http://localhost:63342/AdminLTE-2.3.11/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:110:313) <span ng-bind-html="item.id | highlight: $select.search" class="hide">
```

heres the controller :

```
angular.module('Dashboard')
.controller('DashboardCtrl',
    ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var dashboard = this;

        dashboard.toto="ddazzzz";
       // $scope.vard="ddd";
        alert(dashboard.toto);

    }]);
```

i didnt find what is the problem..?

Comment: You can go to the url that the error provided and see the problem: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=highlightFilterProvider%20%3C-%20highlightFilter. In your case one of controllers trying to inject the highlight filter but there is no one. Can you share with us the full code (html and other relevant js files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, it appears you are using a highlight filter (probably like `{{ ctrl.toto | highlight }}`) which is not registered. It should be registered to a module, just like you register your controller.

Comment: Glad this is the case. Please accept the answer to indicate your question got resolved ;) ...

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `empty module dependency`, also since you use `this` keyword inside controller , then there is no need of `$scope`, use `controller as` syntax.

DEMO :

```js
angular.module('Dashboard',[])
.controller('DashboardCtrl', function () {
        var dashboard = this;
        dashboard.toto="ddazzzz";
       // $scope.vard="ddd";
        alert(dashboard.toto);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="Dashboard" ng-controller="DashboardCtrl as vm">
{{vm.toto}}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks ser ..but i addes angular.module('Dashboard',[]) but it doesnt work

Comment: @fourfour: glad to help, further inject the `filter` in the controller as well.